# Calculating a y value for several x values, such that they are displayed without overlapping (in R)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, na

I have some data that I'm trying to display in R where each data point consists of two x values that are connected by a line.  I'm trying to create a function that allocates a y value for each so that the lines can be displayed without overlapping - the y value is arbitrary, but the idea is to display it at the lowest integer value of y between 1 and 6 inclusively which doesn't overlap with any preceding value.

Something like this:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1yzp.png)

My strategy is to create a loop to calculate a y value for each datapoint by testing all proceeding datapoints to see if their endpoint (x2) is greater than the start point (x1) of the datapoint in question.  The idea is to create a list of height levels which conflict with the current value, and then set the y value to the lowest non-conflicting value.  Here is my code, which unfortunately doesn't do what I wanted to, instead returning NA for all y values except the last, which it gives as 1.  What have I done wrong?

```
calculate.height <- function(i) {
  if (i==1){height <- 1}
  else {
    bad.height.list <- c()
    for (j in i-1){
      if (x2[j] > x1[i] - 0.01) {append(bad.height.list,y[j])}
    }

    bad.levels <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) %in% bad.height.list
    height <- min(which(bad.levels==FALSE))

  }
  return(height)
}

x1 <- c(1,1.5,2.7,3,4.75,9,11,15,15.1,18)
x2 <- c(2,4,3,7,6,9.5,17,15.6,24,19)

y <- c()

for (i in length(x1))  {
  y[i] <- calculate.height(i)
}
```

Comment: it would be useful if you would add your expected vector `y` in the post for the example in question. in general, please avoid embedded graphics; it's better to put in the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your `for (j in i-1)` is not really looping. It assigns `i-1` to `j`, and hence will iterate only once.

If you want to loop from 1 through (i-1), you have to do `for (j in 1:(i-1))`.

Furthermore, note that you want to `y[j]` to the `bad.height.list`, but merely using `append` does not really append - you gotta assign the result of that to `bad.height.list`.

With the above corrections, your code appears to work:

```
calculate.height <- function(i) {
  if (i == 1) {
    height <- 1
  } else {
    bad.height.list <- c()
    for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
      if (x2[j] > x1[i] - 0.01) {
        bad.height.list <- append(bad.height.list, y[j])
      }
    }
    bad.levels <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) %in% bad.height.list
    height <- min(which(bad.levels == FALSE))
  }
  return(height)
}

y <- c()

for (n in 1:length(x1)) {
  y[n] <- calculate.height(n)
}
y
[1] 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 1
```

Please note, though, that it's not good practice to use variables defined in the global scope (e.g. `y`) inside your function.